# Yii Framework - How to run functional test case in background with phpunit/selenium2

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am developing a application with the functional (with phpunit/selenium2) test case. I have to attached the pre-commit hook to a functional testing. So when ever i try to commit something it opens the browser and checks the all test case and work as accepted buttakes a lot of time.
can i some how run this browser process in background ?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by 'run in the background'? Surely you want the commit to wait for the tests to finish.

If you want to keep the browser windows from popping up while you're working on something else, the answer is to make them pop up on a different desktop: either a different machine or (if you're running them on [X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)) on a different X server.

If you're using Selenium 2 with WebDrivers, this is easily accomplished by starting your own Selenium server and using `RemoteWebDriver` objects in your tests that connect to it (constructed with the URL of the Selenium server).

I would advise against doing long tests before a commit. Commits are deliberate decisions to save the present state of the code base for posterity, so the action of committing should be deliberate: you decide you want to do it, you execute the commit action, you write the commit message to document what you're committing and why, and you're done. Inserting long tests will make the final prompt for the commit message interrupt your activity: you may be annoyed by it or miss it altogether. Better run the tests first and make them leave some kind of 'OK' mark that the commit hook can test for.